# Click slide indicator dot and show relevant slide

Tags: jquery, optimization

***Note: I have updated the code to include suggestion from an answer***

I am building a custom slideshow and I am nearing the end of this personal project. One functionality I am looking to add is selecting the slide indicator/dot and the relevant slide coming into view. However, the ideal operation would be the following:

- Current `#slide1`
- Select the dot `#slide3Dot` to show `#slide3`
- The slideshow cycles to show `#slide2`
- Then moves onto `#slide3`. Highlights dot `#slide3Dot`

I have got the basic operation of the slideshow working and linked up the dot for those slides. The click function of the dots is working to a point, but the way it cycles through `#slide1`, skips `#slide2`, then loads `#slide3` could be better by cycling through.

I'm not expecting to be given the answer outright but if people have any guidance/tips that would be great.

Another point I'll add is that I have noticed that there is a lot of duplication. Is some of this avoidable?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.slide:eq(-1)').addClass('last');
$('.dot:first').addClass('active');
$('.slide:first').addClass('active').delay($duration).queue(function () {
    $(this).addClass('show-text');
});
$('.slide:eq(1)').addClass('next');

});

var $classes = 'last active show-text next';
var $duration = 1250;

// Start of Recently updated
$('.dot').on('click' , function(){   // the dot click
  
   var $This = $(this);
   var GetIndex = $This.closest('li').index() + 1;

   $('.dot').removeClass('active').filter($This).addClass('active');
  
  $('.slide').dequeue();
  $('.slide').removeClass($classes);
   
  $('#slide' + GetIndex ).addClass('active').delay($duration).queue(function () {
$(this).addClass('show-text');
  });
  $('.slide').eq(($('.slide.active').index() - 1) % $('.slide').length).addClass('last');
  $('.slide').eq(($('.slide.active').index() + 1) % $('.slide').length).addClass('next');

});

// End of recently updated

$('.button').click(function moveSlide() {

var $active = $('.slide.active');
var $prevSlide = $('.slide').eq(($active.index() - 1) % $('.slide').length);
var $afterPrevSlide = $('.slide').eq(($active.index() - 2) % $('.slide').length);
var $nextSlide = $('.slide').eq(($active.index() + 1) % $('.slide').length);
var $slideAfterNext = $('.slide').eq(($active.index() + 2) % $('.slide').length);
var $tagNextDot = $('#' + $prevSlide.attr('id') + 'Dot' );
var $tagPrevDot = $('#' + $nextSlide.attr('id') + 'Dot' );

$active.dequeue();
$('.slide').removeClass($classes)
$('.dot').removeClass('active');

if ($(this).is("#prev")) {

    $active.addClass('next');
    $tagNextDot.addClass('active');
    $prevSlide.addClass('active').delay($duration).queue(function () {
        $(this).addClass('show-text');
    });
    $afterPrevSlide.addClass('last');

} else {
    $active.addClass('last');
    $tagPrevDot.addClass('active');
    $nextSlide.addClass('active').delay($duration).queue(function () {
        $(this).addClass('show-text');
    });
    $slideAfterNext.addClass('next');
}

});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
}

/* Slides */
.slide-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  left: 140%;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 1.25s;
  box-shadow: -10px 0px 21px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.slide h2 {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.slide.active.show-text h2 {
  display: block;
  animation: reveal-text 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes reveal-text {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

#slide1 {
  background-image: radial-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)
    ), url('https://picsum.photos/1250/1600/?random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#slide2 {
  background-image: radial-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)
    ),  url('https://picsum.photos/1200/1600/?random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#slide3 {
  background-image: radial-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)
    ), url('https://picsum.photos/1200/1500/?random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#slide4 {
  background-image: radial-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)
    ), url('https://picsum.photos/1300/1600/?random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide.last {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.slide.active {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slide.next {
  left: 70%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dots-wrapper {
  z-index: 10;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dots-wrapper li {
  display: inline;
}

.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.dot.active {
  background-color: red;
  border-color: red;
}

/* Buttons */
.button-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
  color: #ddd;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-wrapper">
  <div id="slide1" class="slide">
    <h2>Slide One.</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="slide2" class="slide">
    <h2>Slide Two.</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="slide3" class="slide">
    <h2>Slide Three.</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="slide4" class="slide">
    <h2>Slide Four.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrapper"> 
    <button id="prev" class="button">Prev.</button>
    <button id="next" class="button">Next.</button>
  </div>
  <ul class="dots-wrapper">
    <li>
      <span id="slide1Dot" class="dot"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span id="slide2Dot" class="dot"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span id="slide3Dot" class="dot"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span id="slide4Dot" class="dot"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a very good job .. the click of `.dot`s you can start from getting its `li` index then use the index to show/hide the slides

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.slide:eq(-1)').addClass('last');
    $('.dot:first').addClass('active');
    $('.slide:first').addClass('active').delay($duration).queue(function () {
        $(this).addClass('show-text');
    });
    $('.slide:eq(1)').addClass('next');

});

var $classes = 'last active show-text next';
var $duration = 1250;
$('.dot').on('click' , function(){   // the dot click
   var $This = $(this);
   var GetIndex = $This.closest('li').index(); // get this li index
   $('.dot').removeClass('active').filter($This).addClass('active');   // remove class active from other .dots and add the active class to the click one
   alert(GetIndex);
});
$('.button').click(function moveSlide() {

    var $active = $('.slide.active');
    var $prevSlide = $('.slide').eq(($active.index() - 1) % $('.slide').length);
    var $afterPrevSlide = $('.slide').eq(($active.index() - 2) % $('.slide').length);
    var $nextSlide = $('.slide').eq(($active.index() + 1) % $('.slide').length);
    var $slideAfterNext = $('.slide').eq(($active.index() + 2) % $('.slide').length);
    var $tagNextDot = $('#' + $prevSlide.attr('id') + 'Dot' );
    var $tagPrevDot = $('#' + $nextSlide.attr('id') + 'Dot' );

    $active.dequeue();
    $('.slide').removeClass($classes)
    $('.dot').removeClass('active');

    if ($(this).is("#prev")) {

        $active.addClass('next');
        $tagNextDot.addClass('active');
        $prevSlide.addClass('active').delay($duration).queue(function () {
            $(this).addClass('show-text');
        });
        $afterPrevSlide.addClass('last');

    } else {
        $active.addClass('last');
        $tagPrevDot.addClass('active');
        $nextSlide.addClass('active').delay($duration).queue(function () {
            $(this).addClass('show-text');
        });
        $slideAfterNext.addClass('next');
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
}

/* Slides */
.slide-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70%;
  left: 140%;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 1.25s;
  box-shadow: -10px 0px 21px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.slide h2 {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.slide.active.show-text h2 {
  display: block;
  animation: reveal-text 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes reveal-text {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

#slide1 {
  background-image: radial-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)
    ), url('https://picsum.photos/1250/1600/?random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#slide2 {
  background-image: radial-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)
    ),  url('https://picsum.photos/1200/1600/?random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#slide3 {
  background-image: radial-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)
    ), url('https://picsum.photos/1200/1500/?random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#slide4 {
  background-image: radial-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35)
    ), url('https://picsum.photos/1300/1600/?random');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide.last {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}

.slide.active {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slide.next {
  left: 70%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.dots-wrapper {
  z-index: 10;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dots-wrapper li {
  display: inline;
}

.dot {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.dot.active {
  background-color: red;
  border-color: red;
}

/* Buttons */
.button-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
  color: #ddd;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-wrapper">
  <div id="slide1" class="slide">
    <h2>Slide One.</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="slide2" class="slide">
    <h2>Slide Two.</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="slide3" class="slide">
    <h2>Slide Three.</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="slide4" class="slide">
    <h2>Slide Four.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrapper"> 
    <button id="prev" class="button">Prev.</button>
    <button id="next" class="button">Next.</button>
  </div>
  <ul class="dots-wrapper">
    <li>
      <span id="slide1Dot" class="dot"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span id="slide2Dot" class="dot"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span id="slide3Dot" class="dot"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span id="slide4Dot" class="dot"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Note:** its not a full answer but Its explain the idea of using `li` index to get the num of the clicked `.dot`

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. I think I see what is happening. I implemented the following line `$('#slide' + GetIndex ).addClass('active');` in a pen but cannot be sure if this is the path you were guiding me down. The immediate problem I have is that `index()` is set to `0` so the `.slide` it adds the class to is always one out. Did I explain that well enough?

Comment: @Bagseye I saw your updated question .. you did a great job .. +1 .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: I have an issue with the level of duplicate code I have used. Would you say much of this is avoidable?

Comment: Look @Bagseye if you don't mind let me say an advice .. for sure you can use a `function` s to simplify your code and avoid the duplicated code even you can make a plugin with this code .. But not in this stage .. while your code working now .. leave it and go to the next step on your design  .. Over time you'll know a lot about things and then you can simplify it better than anyone ;)